# neither ssplit.htmlBoundariesToDiscard nor clean.xmlTags working in German

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using the German components of CoreNLP and trying to cleanup HTML tags from text. I tried both the `cleanxml` annotator (`clean.xmltags = .*`) and the relevant option of `ssplit` (`ssplit.htmlBoundariesToDiscard = p,text,img,a`) and nothing has worked.

Are these case sensitive (I tried both `p` and `P` together, didn't seem to make a difference)? Does this have anything to do with the fact that the text is in German?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is a completely changed answer!

I was running Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 and ran this command in the distribution folder:

```
java -Xmx6g -cp "*:." -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,cleanxml,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse -file sample_german.html -outputFormat text
```

I put a German sentence in between some basic HTML tags and the output had the tags removed.  Does this command work for your documents?

I am not sure how you are calling the pipeline but the above should work for command line.  If you are using a .prop file, make sure you have cleanxml as the annotator after tokenize as in this example:

```
annotators = tokenize,cleanxml,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse
```

Please let me know if its still not working!

Comment: The [Stanford NLP webpage](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) -- sections Using the Stanford CoreNLP API and Annotator options -- says otherwise. Also, the cleanxml annotator does in fact exist in the github code and it even complains when there is "flawed" XML, unless you activate the corresponding option to ignore this.
So, to me, this strongly suggests that there is code in there that's supposed to do what it says.
Could you at least point me to someone who knows more about this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi just to be clear, you are definitely right that cleanxml annotator will strip xml tags, what I meant to say is that I'm not sure we have something that will take in an HTML doc, get rid of all the junk, and just give you the text, e.g. if you feed in the HTML of a news article and just want the text of the news article...I will look into your issue more closely over the next few days and get back to you soon!

Comment: Thanks, that would be great. 
My input is not an entire HTML file. It is just some text that happens to have a few HTML tags inside it (e.g. <p>, <img>, <a> and such). I would expect cleanxml to be able to remove these, regardless of the language... Unless I'm using it wrong.

Comment: Actually this raises another question in this case: what is the big difference between cleaning XML versus cleaning HTML (besides the fact that XML us much more generic)?

Comment: Hello again, sorry it took so long. So I tried the command line tool, exactly how you wrote it above. My sample text had only a few <p> (including some <p>&nbsp;</p>) marks in it. Unfortunately, it only worked partially. Every <p> or <p>&nbsp;</p> that the software thought was marking the beginning or the end of a sentence was removed. But the ones that it thought are inside a sentence were left alone. This was when using "tokenize,cleanxml,ssplit".

When using only "tokenize,cleanxml" it doesn't work at all (no text output). Same case from the API outputs the text unchanged.

Comment: Could you post a short text snippet that's not working here and then I can investigate your specific situation more closely!

Comment: Sure, here is the simplest sample text I've been using.

<P>Liebe Community</P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>Nun habe ich die Samplecom 1.0 (inkl. Adapter). Nach dem einschalten muss ich jedes Mal einen manuellen Gerätewechsel vornehmen, weil&nbsp;die Harmony&nbsp;default-mässig nur den Receiver steuert. </P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>Meine Frage daher ist: wie schaffe ich es, dass die Harmony automatisch die Box steuert, die Lautstärke aber weiterhin über den Receiver geregelt wird? </P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>Vielen Dank für Eure Antworten. Wenn das Thema behandelt wurde: sorry!</P><P>&nbsp;</P><P>Gruss</P><P>Stefan</P>

Comment: In general, I will have a few other tags besides <p>, such a <strong>,<blockquote>,<a> etc.
But I would already be happy even if I manage to only remove all of the <p>'s.